# Unexpected Kafka request of type METADATA during SASL handshake

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to connect Kafka Java Client to a Kafka broker using SASL Plain. But when I try to send a message from the Producer, the Kafka Server logs the following error:

```
[2020-04-30 14:48:14,955] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=0] Failed authentication with /127.0.0.1 (Unexpected Kafka request of type METADATA during SASL handshake.) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
```

By the looks, the producer tries to send a metadata request, before the SASL handshake. How can I do the handshake before sending the message?

Following is my `kafka_server_jaas.conf` file, which is used for Kafka Server.

```
KafkaServer {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
    username="admin"
    password="admin-secret"
    user_admin="admin-secret";
};

Client {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
    username="admin"
    password="admin-secret";
};
```

Following is my `zookeeper_jaas.conf` file, which is used for the zookeeper:

```
Server {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
    username="admin"
    password="admin-secret"
    user_admin="admin-secret";
};
```

In my Java producer, I set the following properties:

```java
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
properties.put("sasl.jaas.config", "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"admin\" password=\"admin_secret\"");
properties.put("sasl.mechanisms", "PLAIN");
properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
KafkaProducer kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer(properties);
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing?

Comment: A semicolon should terminate the string value set for `sasl.jaas.config`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to specify [`security.protocol`](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security.protocol), otherwise by default, Kafka clients do not use `SASL`.

In your client properties, add:

```
properties.put("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL");
```

There's also `SASL_PLAINTEXT` but it's not recommended to use the `PLAIN` mechanism over `SASL_PLAINTEXT` as effectively the password will be exchanged in cleartext.