kafka bitnami helm chart ssl issue
Subject of the issue
mtls and tls not working for kafka helm chart  for internal communication
Your environment

RHEL
Kubernetes
Bitnami kafka helm chart

Steps to reproduce
clientProtocol: plaintext

if we change to mtls its not working showing ssl handshake error
Note: empty by default for backwards compatibility reasons, find more information at https://github.com/bitnami/charts/pull/8902/
externalClientProtocol: mtls
interBrokerProtocol: plaintext 

Expected behaviour
While creating topic its should not show any error and has connection with zookeeper or alertmanager helm chart with mtls or tls
Actual behaviour
Showing ssl handshake error
Log
2024-05-09 11:54:44,679] INFO [SocketServer listenerType=BROKER, nodeId=0] Failed authentication with /<ip> (channel(Unexpected Kafka request of type METADATA during SASL handshake.) (

Tried with newly created jks certificate and pass as secret for each broker

The error looks to be about SASL, not SSL. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61520656/3543371
